# Why can't i download pygame with pip

Tags: python

i get this when i run `pip install pygame`
 `distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.3 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

I don't know what to do so i quit the installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message means there's no prebuilt binary package available for your python environment in PyPI and it tried to build the package from the source, but it failed because the MSVC build tools is not installed in your system.

So there are two solutions.

1. As you can see at [this](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files), currently there is a binary package for Python 3.10, but none for Python 3.11. So, I recommend to install Python 3.10 and try to install Pygame from that.
2. Install MSVC build tools and install the source package. It maybe required to install extra dependencies.